# Using return value of findstr batch

Tags: batch-file, svn, findstr

I have script:

```
svn log --incremental -l 1 -r 384092 -v http://svn/someFolder/ | findstr "ws/wsjava" | findstr /C:"   D"
```

I get svnlog for specified revision 384092  , and check if there exist string with `ws/wsjava` and   `D`. How further I can use that? - if some string was returned from findstr - call some other batch.

Comment: Use [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution).  Just put `&& call otherbatch.bat` at the end of your line.

Comment: `svn log --incremental -l 1 -r 384092 -v http://svn/someFolder/ | findstr "ws/wsjava" | findstr /C:"   D" && call otherbatch.bat`

Answer (score 2):

Use `svn log --search foo` or `svn log --search FOO --search-and BAR` instead.

Read [`svn log` command reference in SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
svn log --incremental -l 1 -r 384092 -v http://svn/someFolder/ | findstr "ws/wsjava" | findstr /C:" D" && call otherbatch.bat
```

Thanx rojo.